Adverse Events API data is not updated for the month of April
We are using below API to fetch the data but it seems API data is not updated for April month data as it shows last updated as 2024-05-01 in the response and therefore we are not able to get the latest data for the month of April 2024:
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20240401+TO+20240430]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22BSZ%22&limit=1000
But when go to below URL and search for BSZ product code and put the dates as 04/01/2024 and 04/30/2024, the updated data is present on https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/search.cfm
Kindly help as we are using the API to fetch the data.
Thanks, Shailendra J
